# I want to get bottom div margin from top from window screen by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one div that is middle in the screen and when I am clicking on previous div I want auto scroll of the screen and start with next div of that, I am working with Bootstrap to make responsive design. I wrote code as following..

> 1. I got space from top to div by **valuescrollckPart7=offset().top**.
> 2. And scroll screen by **$("html, body").animate({scrollTop: valuescrollckPart7})**

but it is not working properly in all screens(mobile, desktop, tablet).

Html code:

```
 <div class="open hidden ckPart7ScrollWindow7">        
      <div class="heading">
              <div>6. Payment Method</div>
      </div>           
 </div>
```

javascript code:

```
 var valuescrollckPart7 = $('.ckPart7ScrollWindow7').offset().top;
 $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: valuescrollckPart7});
```

So please suggest some way to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean for the fist part, I however, can help you with responsive design.

Responsive design is done with [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

You can make diffrent CSS tags that 'trigger' when the screen the viewer is watching it on is smaller then the min.width you've assigned to it.

```
/* For mobile phones: */
[class*="col-"] {
width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* For desktop: */
.col-1 {width: 8.33%;}
.col-2 {width: 16.66%;}
.col-3 {width: 25%;}
.col-4 {width: 33.33%;}
.col-5 {width: 41.66%;}
.col-6 {width: 50%;}
.col-7 {width: 58.33%;}
.col-8 {width: 66.66%;}
.col-9 {width: 75%;}
.col-10 {width: 83.33%;}
.col-11 {width: 91.66%;}
.col-12 {width: 100%;}
}
```

Comment: Responsive design mean bootsrap collums. suppose If you are using three collums in one row than second row margin from top will increase.